# How to resample hourly this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset, I'm trying to have a mean of "AC_POWER" every hour but isn't working properly. The dataset have 20-22 value every 15 minutes. I want to have something like this:

```
 DATE              AC_POWER
'15-05-2020 00:00' 400
'15-05-2020 01:00' 500
'15-05-2020 02:00' 500
'15-05-2020 03:00' 500
```

How to solve this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
    
df = df.reset_index()
df['DATE_TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df = df.resample('H', on='DATE_TIME').mean()

>>> df.head(10).to_dict()
{'AC_POWER': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 
 'DAILY_YIELD': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 
 'DATE_TIME': {0: '15-05-2020 00:00', 1: '15-05-2020 00:00', 2: '15-05-2020 00:00', 3: '15-05-2020 00:00', 
               4: '15-05-2020 00:00', 5: '15-05-2020 00:00', 6: '15-05-2020 00:00', 7: '15-05-2020 00:00', 
               8: '15-05-2020 00:00', 9: '15-05-2020 00:00'}, 
 'DC_POWER': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 
 'PLANT_ID': {0: 4135001, 1: 4135001, 2: 4135001, 3: 4135001, 4: 4135001, 5: 4135001, 
              6: 4135001, 7: 4135001, 8: 4135001, 9: 4135001}, 
 'SOURCE_KEY': {0: '1BY6WEcLGh8j5v7', 1: '1IF53ai7Xc0U56Y', 2: '3PZuoBAID5Wc2HD', 3: '7JYdWkrLSPkdwr4', 
                4: 'McdE0feGgRqW7Ca', 5: 'VHMLBKoKgIrUVDU', 6: 'WRmjgnKYAwPKWDb', 7: 'ZnxXDlPa8U1GXgE', 
                8: 'ZoEaEvLYb1n2sOq', 9: 'adLQvlD726eNBSB'}, 
 'TOTAL_YIELD': {0: 6259559.0, 1: 6183645.0, 2: 6987759.0, 3: 7602960.0, 4: 7158964.0, 
                 5: 7206408.0, 6: 7028673.0, 7: 6522172.0, 8: 7098099.0, 9: 6271355.0}}
```

EDIT: I tried with a different dataset and the same code I've posted and it worked!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your data. You can include the data as text/code using `df.head(10).to_dict()` Also, what do you mean by "isn't working properly"? What is your current and expected output?

Comment: `df.resample('H', on='DATE_TIME')["AC_POWER"].mean()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your date as an index first, the following does this and computes the mean for windows of 15 minutes:

```
df.set_index('DATE_TIME').resample('15T').mean()
```

Also, make sure your date vector is correctly formated.

Comment: how to correct the date vector?  it seems to work but it starts with different date

Comment: use datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d %B, %Y"), you can find examples here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `DataFrame.resample`:

```
df.resample(rule='H', on='DATE_TIME')['AC_POWER'].mean()
```